# How to solve import error for Azure text analytics

Tags: python, azure, text, nlp

import error for TextAnalyticsClient
I am following Microsoft official document for sentiment analysis.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/sentiment-opinion-mining/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-python

However, I am having import error to import TextAnalyticsClient.
This code cause error message like this.

from azure.ai.textanalytics import TextAnalyticsClient

ImportError: cannot import name 'is_rest'

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3):

I tried to reproduce the issue and got the same for both imports like:

> Error:

```
import azure core credentials could not be resolved pylance(reportmissingimports)

import azure ai text analytics could not be resolved pylance(reportmissingimports)
```

#### Steps to resolve issue:

1. Open Command Palette in your VS Code Project by pressing `ctrl + shift + p` and type **Python: Select Interpreter** and click on that option.

[image: Open Cmd Palette Python Interpreter]

2. Select the **Python Interpreter** as it shows the suitable version for that like in below screenshot:

[image: Select Python Interpreter]

Or If you have multiple versions, it shows the ***recommended interpreter*** and select that,  like in the below screenshot:

[image: Select Recommended Python Interpreter if multiple]

Then after a few seconds, the imports error lines can be fixed by that interpreter.

3. Run the script you pasted in the python file from given [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/language-service/sentiment-opinion-mining/quickstart?pivots=programming-language-python) as you can see the output in below screenshot:

[image]

#### Updated Answer:

To do this with [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/install), the following steps are:

1. Installed the Jupyter Notebook using pip in my local system command prompt (admininstrator mode) using this command `pip install jupyterlab`

After installation, run Jupyter Lab with this command `jupyter-lab`

2. Then it will open the Jupyter Notebook in any browser.

[image]

3. Run the package first using this command:

`pip install azure-ai-textanalytics==5.1.0`

[image]

4. Paste your code and click on the play button to run and it run successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I usually use Jupyter Notebook for the coding.
How can I do these procedures by Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: @KOTA - Updated the answer regarding procedure/workflow with Jupyter Notebook. Please check!